# Fitting of mesostructure diffraction peaks

Tags: software-recommendations, x-ray-diffraction, mesoscopic-physics

I've got synchrotron X-ray powder diffraction data where nice mesostructure diffraction peaks are observed at a very low angles. Does anybody know how to gain relevant information from these data? Does there exist an *ad hoc* software to manage/fit these data?

As observed by TEM, the mesostructure is constituted of almost circular very thin lamellae forming a sort of chain containing tens of these lamellae.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3810/24) can get some light.

Comment: Thanks for, but actually the mesostructure peaks are related to the ordered arrangment of the nanometric particles and are found at very low diffraction angles. The normal Bragg peaks coming from the crystal structure are found at larger diffracting angles.

Comment: +1. Various peak fitting software exist. Could you show us the data? I think it would help to get this question answered!